# Can not solve windows boot repair issue

Tags: windows-8.1, grub, ubuntu-14.04, bootrepair

Sometime ago I installed Ubuntu 14.04.5 on my system which had windows 8.1 pre-installed. Now I have decided to uninstall Ubuntu. So I deleted the partitions and tried to perform boot repair. So I created a bootable windows drive and through that went to command prompt. There I typed the following commands -

`Bootrec.exe /FixMbr 
Bootrec.exe /FixBoot`

and restarted the system.

But this didn't solved my problem. I still get the `grub` window when I start or restart the system. (And after giving the `exit` command I still get both Ubuntu and windows options. Clicking on ubuntu option directs me to the same grub window).

I am not sure if these are complete commands to solve the issue. What should I do? Any kind of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me but too long ago to give step by step. What I would do is connect the drive via USB to another system and insure all partitions were deleted, and run WD Diag program and write zeros to the drive. Then use disk management to create a partition and format it. At that point it should be an all windows disk.